# NodeJS event loop callback limits per iteration

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, libuv

Every cycle of the NodeJS event loop synchronously clears a maximum number of callbacks queued for each phase.

From NodeJS website:

> when the event loop enters a given phase, it will perform any operations specific to that phase, then execute callbacks in that phase's queue until the queue has been exhausted or the maximum number of callbacks has executed.

Event loop phases: `timers --> pending callbacks --> idle, prepare --> poll --> check --> close callbacks`

For example in the poll phase the limit is set by libuv:

> To prevent the poll phase from starving the event loop, libuv (the C library that implements the Node.js event loop and all of the asynchronous behaviors of the platform) also has a hard maximum (system dependent) before it stops polling for more events.

My question is:

- **Where can I find these hard limits per phase/iteration?**
- Bonus: Is there a programmatic way to get the current size of each phase's queue?

Comment: There is no access to libuv internals like event queue depths from within Javascript in nodejs.  You could, of course, access/modify the source and recompile your own version of nodejs that provided more info.  This question reads like an XY problem where you seem to think you want to know more about queue depths in order to solve some problem, but you haven't described the actual problem, therefore we can't help you with better ways to solve that problem (that perhaps are supported).

Comment: *Where can I find these hard limits per phase/iteration?*  Any limits like this would be in the source code.  It's all [here](https://github.com/nodejs/node).

Comment: "*use that information to throttle incoming calls*" - no, that won't work.